# Call instruction - preceding ?@_ in references?

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly, call

Seems to be a question of no importance, but I'm just curious: Is there a deeper meaning of the preceeding (single/double) `?`-marks, `@`-signs or `__` underscores in these different `call` instructions?

```
call ??2@YAPAXI@Z
call ??0CAdviseObject@CBLObject@@QAE@PAUIDispatch@@PAVCBLInstance@@@Z
call ?StartAutoReconnect@CBLObject@@IAEXIH@Z
call @__security_check_cookie@4
call __SEH_epilog
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading `?` identifies a C++ name mangled symbol. Two `??` signify operators, constructors, destructors, constant strings, and various compiler generator functions. For example `??0` is a constructor. [This site](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/msvc/language/decoration/index.htm) has a good breakdown of the mangling pieces used by MSVC.

A leading underscore `_` can either be due to the calling convention or due to the CRT/compiler identification standard. They will prefix all of their symbols with [two leading underscores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9.aspx) `__` as a way to help prevent name collisions:

> In Microsoft C++, identifiers with two leading underscores are
>   reserved for compiler implementations.

Answer (score 2):

These are so-called "mangled" or "decorated" names. You can use undname utility from Visual Stduio to demangle them:

```
void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)
public: __thiscall CBLObject::CAdviseObject::CAdviseObject(struct IDispatch *,cl
ass CBLInstance *)
protected: void __thiscall CBLObject::StartAutoReconnect(unsigned int,int)
```

For more info: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deaxefa7.aspx).